# Sending email in PHP via SMTP. Hide server IP

Tags: php, email, networking, smtp

Users of my application can send emails via their SMTP information.

I want to send emails 100% on behalf of their SMTP. If someone starts spamming, I don't want other users to be negatively affected.

But in the received headers, I see my server IP, so I think everyone will be affected.

How can I make sure the server isn't held responsable? I need to make sure 1 person can't mess up everyone else.

Comment: Unless you can't give each user an IP of their own, I guess there'll always be the risk that your IP will be held accountable. You'll have to make damn sure your users don't send spam....

Comment: I've seen CRMs that let you send emails from their server using your SMTP information. How do you think they deal with this?

Comment: I don't know - maybe they have some flood control, or their users' credit card info on file for *some* measure of safety... that said, I'm not completely sure how affected the *originating* IP will be. Usually, most of the anti-spam stuff I see centers around the sending *server*.... but then, it makes total sense to take the originating IP into account, as well. Not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are the middle-man is this scenario, i.e. you are connecting to the SMTP server on behalf of others, it's up to your *application* to deal with spam. You can't solve this just at the network level.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're seeing your server IP in the headers of sent e-mails from PHP, am I right to assume:

1. You're running your own SMTP server (hence "my server IP" in the headers)?
2. Your users have access to this server over SMTP with authentication (probably SASL)?
3. When you submit mail to the SMTP server from PHP, you are using the SMTP credentials to authenticate?

If this is true, you do have some limited options regarding protection against a user who is compromised and sending spam.

The first option is to implement rate limiting in the PHP application, using a persistent store to record number of e-mails sent over a period of time. However, this solution is very limited because it does not cover abuse of the SMTP server itself.

My recommendation would be to investigate a **policy server**, such as [policyd](http://www.policyd.org/) and implement [quotas](http://www.policyd.org/content/quotas). A quota using the SASL username that specifies the maximum rate of sending per hour will help reduce the likelihood of being added to spam blacklists. If the policy server you choose supports notifications of quotas being reached, I would implement that too (allowing you to identify users that are hitting their quotas regularly, indicating something is wrong with the account).

Deciding what rate you want to limit sending to is difficult, since you will have to balance user needs against protection. Perhaps a good starting point would be to monitor the average number of e-mails your users send per hour currently, and use this as a starting point?

Again, the above assumes that the three points indicated above are true. If you are simply passing mail to the SMTP daemon without authentication, or the server is external and cannot be modified, then you are going to have to enforce limits in PHP.